# /boot partition is NTFS on dual-boot Win7/Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ntfs

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire laptop. Windows 7 Home Premium edition was installed on the main drive. I booted to the Ubuntu 12.04 Installation environment and selected the option to Install Ubuntu alonside Windows 7. I now have two data partitions roughly half the size of the HD (NTFS and EXT4) and a /boot partition that is NTFS.

How can i convert the /boot partition to EXT without breaking Ubuntu and Windows 7? I would like to tri-boot it with another Environment if possible, but this is presenting a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the /boot partition is from Ubuntu? and not for Windows? I usually only get to choose from ext4 when doing the /boot partition so it's really odd that it is ntfs

Comment: How did you ever install Ubuntu and make it so /boot was NTFS?. The only way I am thinking of would be by selecting the manual installation option and doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The boot partition was most probably made by the Windows installer and is its boot partition (unless you can post some evidence to the contrary).

Anyway, there is no way to convert ntfs to ext4.